# Python BeautifulSoup give multiple tags to findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for a way to use findAll to get two tags, in the order they appear on the page.

Currently I have:

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup

def get_soup(url):
    request = requests.get(url)
    page = request.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    get_tags = soup.findAll('hr' and 'strong')
    for each in get_tags:
        print each
```

If I use that on a page with only 'em' or 'strong' in it then it will get me all of those tags, if I use on one with both it will get 'strong' tags.

Is there a way to do this?  My main concern is preserving the order in which the tags are found.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You could [pass a list](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list), to find any of the given tags:

```
tags = soup.find_all(['hr', 'strong'])
```

Comment: I think soup.findAll(['hr', 'strong']) could do the job, find_all does not run.

Comment: @r0sk: `find_all()` is the correct name on beautifulsoup4. Click the link in the answer. `findAll()` is for BeautifulSoup 3 that is replaced by  Beautiful Soup 4.

Answer (score 14):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
get_tags = soup.findAll(re.compile(r'(hr|strong)'))
```

The expression `r'(hr|strong)'` will find either `hr` tags or `strong` tags.

Answer (score 2):

To find *multiple* tags, you can use the `,` [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp), where you can specify multiple tags separated by a comma `,`.

To use a CSS selector, use the [`.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `.find()`, or [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of `.find_all()`.

For example, to select all `<hr>` *and* `strong` tags, separate the tags with a `,`:

```
tags = soup.select('hr, strong')
```