# Beautiful soup queries

Tags: python, lambda, beautifulsoup, operator-keyword

I'm struggling to have queries in BS with multiple conditions of the type AND or OR.
From what I read I have to use lambda.
As an example, I'm looking for tags that match either "span", {"class":"green"} or tag.name == "h1" on the page http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html

I manage to get them separately using the lambda syntax:
    `bsObj.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == "h1")`  will return h1
    `bsObj.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == "span", {"class":"green"})` wil return span green

Or I can get all "span" tags and "h1" :
    `bsObj.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == "span" or tag.name == "h1")`  return span green and red as well as h1

But I don't manage to get the span of **class green or h1**, as the following code does not provide the right result :
`bsObj.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == "span", {"class":"green"} or tag.name == "h1")`

Can please someone explain me the right way to do it in **one** query ? Goal here is not only to get the result but rather understand the syntax. Thanks !

(using Python 3.4)
PS : I think this issue is different from the the one here:   [BeautifulSoup findAll() given multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes) as well as a variation of [Python BeautifulSoup give multiple tags to findAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648660/python-beautifulsoup-give-multiple-tags-to-findall?rq=1) (as we want a specific attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access attributes using the `tag['<attr_name>']` syntax. Check `tag.attrs` to see what this dictionary contains exactly. Anyway, you might be able to search for green using the `class` attribute. Since it is a [multi-valued attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) you might need to use:

```
'green' in tag['class']
```

And for your `lambda` construct, you should make use of `and` as well as `or`:

```
lambda t: (t.name == 'span' and 'green' in t.get('class',[])) or t.name == 'h1'
```

Comment: Hi Matthias and many thanks for your answer. Can you please provide the full syntax? I've tried: `bsObj.findAll(lambda t: (t.name == "span" and t['class'] == u'green') or t.name == "h1")` and it only returns h1.

Comment: You need to check first if `tag['class']` returns a single value or a list. According to the standard it should return a list but it might vary. Read the [doc on attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) and multi-values attributes do decide whether form suits your needs.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner I just don't get it. Would be great if you can provide a working syntax maybe I can understand then...

Comment: What does `for t in bsObj.findAll(name='span'): print(t['class'])` outputs? Feel free to share only a few lines.

Comment: It uses the multi-valued attributes syntax, then. Answer updated.