# Python - How to use findAll method to search for two tags(WebScraping)

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to use findAll method to find for two tags 'div' with class:None and 'li'

```
soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"entry-content"}).findAll('div', attrs={"class":None} or 'li')
```

because this is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup findAll() given multiple classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725760/beautifulsoup-findall-given-multiple-classes)

Comment: `li` is a tag, not a class...

Comment: i know div and li is a tag but how can i find both of them with findAll if there are so many other tags present

Comment: So you want to find all `div` and `li` elements that do not have a class?

Comment: Yes, but i would also like to know if 'div' has a class or 'li' has a class or both has or both don't. How findAll method will help to do so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python BeautifulSoup give multiple tags to findAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648660/python-beautifulsoup-give-multiple-tags-to-findall)