# Extract entire html tag (including child tags) with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the entire content of a HTML element which then I want to parse. More precisely, I have a web-page which I crawl and I can identify a `<select>` tag with Beautiful Soup, but I want to access its child tags.

So far I have:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS

search_url = 'http://example.com/'
response = urllib2.urlopen(self.search_url)
html = response.read()

soup = BS(html)
html_manufacturer_list = soup.findAll("select", attrs = {"id":"manufacturerID"})
```

The actual HTML I'm parsing looks like:

```
<select id="manufacturerID">
   <option value="1">Abarth</option>
   <option value="2">ABC</option>
   <option value="3">Acura</option>
   <option value="4">Alfa Romeo</option>
   ...
</select>
```

But when running the above Python code the `html_manufacturer_list` object identifies only the parent `select` tag and has no information related to its child `option` tags.

```
<select id="manufacturerID"> </select>
```

Searching for `<option>` tags is .. not an option, since there are multiple `<select>` tags with options on the webpage.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated on how to identify or extract the `<option>` tag information from the page.

Comment: this might help: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648660/python-beautifulsoup-give-multiple-tags-to-findall -> tell it to find both select AND option...

Comment: @ewcz Are you suggesting `html_manufacturer_list.contents` ? Because I get an error that there is no attribute `contents`...

Comment: @Saskia How would you put that in code? I'm finding difficulties getting the syntax right... `soup.findAll(["select", "option"], attrs = {"id":"selectMake1-ds"})` doesn't return the `option` tags

Comment: ensure the <option> elements aren't generated via JS on the fly, you will not able to see that from your resulted list in such case -- since `soup.findAll("select")` SHOULD include child option elements.

Comment: @Anzel Aham! Sounds plausible, I'll have to look into that, thanks!

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, not a problem. If that's the case (highly likely), you need to trace the JS ajax call source, and request that endpoint and get the list of the options you're after

Comment: The children are definitely added dynamically, can you share the url?