# AssertionError: 22 columns passed, passed data had 21 columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2014.html"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
column_headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr',limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]
data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:]
player_data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range(len(data_rows))] #PLAYER DATA 

type(soup)
type(data_rows)

df = pd.DataFrame(player_data,columns=column_headers)
```

The error seems to occur in the last line.

Comment: Can you elaborate to make your post clearer?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will help you to revise your question so that you communicate the information that we need to help you.  Learning [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is painful but well worth the effort.

Comment: I will re-post the above with clear content

Comment: "22 columns passed, passed data had 21 columns" is pretty self-descriptive.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the error is pretty straight-forward: your `column_headers` list has 22 columns, but `player_data` entries only have 21. So you need to find which out column is missing and why. Just by visually comparing the entries from the dataframe and the headers list, it appears one of the two first columns is missing. `player_data[0][0]` returns

`1, CLE, Andrew Wiggins, University of Kansas,...` but it should be

`1, 1, CLE, Andrew Wiggins, University of Kansas,...`

The problem is the table itself. Navigate to the website, hover over the table and right-click: inspect.

The first row of data (underneath the 'Rk') consists of 21 `td` and 1 `th` element. The "rk" entry is actually of type `th` and not `td`:

[image: Screenshot of table of provided data]

That is why your

```
player_data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range(len(data_rows))]
```

skips the first column because it is only iterating over `td` elements. Hence the different length. 
I don't know how important the first column is; quick fix would be to drop the Rk column from your headers list.

Alternatively, search for [both `td` and `th` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648660/python-beautifulsoup-give-multiple-tags-to-findall):

```
player_data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll(['td','th'])] for i in range(len(data_rows))]
```