# Concatenating dataframes iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that produces a dataframe with 10 rows and i my goal is to get 135 of these dataframes. I don't want them separate, so I need to concatenate them into one dataframe so that it has 10 rows and 135 labeled columns, but i want to do this efficiently.
The closest i got to what i needed was this:

```
for i in range(len(docs)):
    for l in labels_list:
        df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({l:(my_func(i)})])
```

But obviously this just returns the very last column of the dataframe...

EDIT

Another way:

I appended the result of `my_func` into a list and i now have a list of lists with 135 lists and 10 strings in each list. I want to make a dataframe out of this with 135 columns and 10 rows, but the regular way gives me an error:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_df, columns=labels_list)

ValueError: 135 columns passed, passed data had 10 columns
```

Comment: I suggest you build a list of DataFrames and then perform the concatenation operation just once.

Comment: @nick got a list of dfs, not sure how to concat them so that every 10 row is under one of the 135 columns

Comment: Does each of the DataFrames generated by `my_func` have one column or multiple?

Comment: @flyingdutchman one

Comment: It looks like your function return a *list*? and you manually convert it to a dataframe by calling `pd.DataFrame({l:(my_func(i)})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({labels_list[i]: my_func(i)}) for i in range(len(docs))], axis=1)
```

If you already have the list of dataframes:

```
df = pd.concat(list_of_df, axis=1)
df.columns = labels_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your function `my_func` returns the type `pd.DataFrame`. Your goal is to have 135 columns and each column has the name `l` from `labels_list`. You need to ensure that you will have unique column names as well. The format string `"{} {}".format(str(i), l)` tries to achieve this. You need to be sure that you convert `i` to a `str`. I'm indicating that with the `str()` function here.

Then I would do it like this:

```py
for i in range(len(docs)):
    for l in labels_list:
        df["{} {}".format(str(i), l)] = my_func(i).iloc(:,0)
```

As your function `my_func` has only one column you can also access it by it's name, so like this:

```py
df[l] = my_func(i)["column_name"]
```

I hope this helps. If not please be more specific about your function and try to have a complete minimal working example.
Your problem also seems to be quite similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas?rq=1).

EDIT:
Check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855030/assertionerror-22-columns-passed-passed-data-had-21-columns) for your question edit. That might help.

Comment: this created a 135x135 df and with the same entries (last output of my_func) in every column..

Comment: Then add an assertion like so `assert len(my_func(i)["column_name"]) == 10` to be sure that every column has actually 10 elements/rows.

Comment: what about the repeating values?

Comment: Then try to create a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordinly. As I don't know what is happening in your function `my_func` and what `docs` and `labels_list` is I can't help you any further now.