# How to extract only the text inside a given class or tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using `BeautifulSoup4` for scraping websites. There are only a couple of things in the site that I'm interested in, and most of them are within the tag `article`. However, there are some without `article` tag but inside a `div` tag with class name.

**Source**: an example of the site that I'm trying to scrape is https://news.3m.com/English/3m-stories/3m-details/2020/3M-Foundation-awards-1M-to-four-local-organizations-in-support-of-racial-equity/default.aspx

In the site, I'm only interested in the article which is **not** inside an `article` tag, but is written inside `div` tag with class name `module_body`.

Here's What I have done so far:

- read each URL
- save the websites as `.html` in the directory. (**Reason**: We wanted to make sure the data we collected is not updated, and check the difference few months later)
- after all sites are stored, read each `.html` file
- use `BeautifulSoup` to parse html and extract the text within the tag/class.

**Helper Function**

```
def parse_article(response, tag):
    
    article = [e.get_text() for e in response.find_all(tag)]
   
    article = '\n'.join(article)

    return article



def check_article(response):
    tags_classess_query = [
        ('article'), 
        ('div', {'class': 'module_body'})
    ]
    
    for item in tags_classess_query: 
        print('checking for {}'.format(item))
        
        if response.find(item):
            return item

    return None



# list all html files downloaded
html_files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if '.html' in file]

# loop html_files to process each file
for file in html_files:
    
    filepath = os.path.join(path,file)
    article_file = os.path.splitext(filepath)[0]
    
    # file name to store the extracted text using BS4
    article_file = article_file + '.txt'
    
    
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    
        html = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
        

    
    # check if selected tag exists in HTML. 
    
    tag = check_article(html)
        
    if tag is not None:
        #This is where I'm running into this issue where it still saves all of html page not just the text inside the selected tag/class

        article = parse_article(html, tag)
        
        w = open(article_file, 'w+', encoding='utf-8') 
        w.write(article)
        w.close()

    else:
        print("tag not found for %s" % file)
```

I'm now running into this issue where it doesn't extract text only in the selected tag but everything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were passing `('div',{'class':'module_body'})` instead of `'div',{'class':'module_body'}`. Note the later is 2 separate arguments. So just replace this line in your `parse_article` function.

```
def parse_article(response, tag):
    article = [e.text for e in response.find_all(tag[0],tag[1])]
```

Since your other `tag` doesn't have 2 elements you might get outof Index error so You can use unpacking operator `*`

```
def parse_article(response, tag):
    article = [e.text for e in response.find_all(*tag)]
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is how you wanted to suggest `.find_all([tag[0],tag[1]])`, right?

Comment: No just `soup.findAll(tag[0,tag[1])`. Since `tag = ('div',{'class':'module_body'})`. So it will be `findall('div' , {'class':'module_body'})`

Comment: You are still doing it wrong. When you wanna use multiple tags within `.find_all()`, you need to use them within a list. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20649408/9189799) for better clarity. Thanks.

Comment: But it's not multiple tags though. `'div' , {'class':'module_body'}` is one tag

Comment: Yes, I got you. I didn't notice that you edited your comment to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @SIM good point though if there is just one tag it will throw an error. updated my answer  to handle that.

Comment: Splendid! I was just about to ask you that. You thought of that before I could ask. +1

Comment: @venky__, one thing I realized is that if `*tag` is used in `article` tag, it unpacks to `['a', 'r', 't', 'i', 'c', 'l', 'e']`. For now, I've done this: `if isinstance(tag, str): args = tag else: *args,=tag` Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: @Kuni aghh. Instead of a tuple you can make it an array then `tags_classess_query = [ ['article'], ['div', {'class': 'module_body'}]]`